# Downgrade Kali Linux

Tags: linux-kernel, compiling, kali-linux

I have upgraded my system to KALI Sana 2.0 and kernel 4.0.0-Kali1-amd64. Previously I had the version kali-linux 1.1.0 and kernel 3.18-Kali1-amd64. 
The reason I want to downgrade is that Kali Sana 2.0 is giving me too many problems and doesn't launch the GUI.
Please do not tell me to install a fresh version of Kali as I don't want to lose the data and Apps.

Please help me to downgrade my system to kali-linux 1.1.0 and kernel 3.18-Kali1-amd64.

Comment: You'd better make backup of your data, otherwise consider your data lost.

Comment: I can do that, but how do I go about making a downgrade?!

Comment: Short answer? You don't. I realize this isn't the answer you want to hear, but it's the only real one.

Answer (score 2):

Downgrades are a lot more dangerous than upgrades. You would probably have to switch repository to older version, remove some packages and run dist-upgrade. However, from my limited experience of downgrading on Debian, I'd say it's a lot easier to just backup your data, and then install your programs again - especially if you don't know how to fix things. You might end up in dependency hell.

If you want to list programs installed by you, run command

```
aptitude search '~i!~M'
```

Actually [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages) has numerous answers adressing getting information about installed packages. This might come in handy.

Also, for future, you might want to create separate /home partition. This way you can reinstall OS all you want, and your data will always be there - just aplications will need to be installed, but that isn't a problem.

Comment: Which command can I use to get the list of gnome-menu applications?

Comment: I guess that according to [this page](https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en), you'd have best luck when searching in `/usr/share/applications/`. However, it holds more than just applications. Imho your best bet would be just writing down programs you want to preserve, and install them later. I use various programs, but the list does not exceeds 20 items, which isn't that much. If I forget anything, I can always install it when I need it.